# How to set a click listener on overflow menu - Material Toolbar

Tags: android, listener, android-toolbar

I would like to open the settings activity just by clicking on the overflow button in my Material Toolbar.
How can I setup a click listener on this button ? I don't want to inflate any menu by clicking on it, I just want to load another activity.

Before redesigning my app, I was inflating a menu by overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu`, but now I can't find any method to override that looks like `onOverflowIconClickListener`, or something like this.

I hope my question was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are found here [Menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus)

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu)
return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
// Handle item selection
return when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.new_game -> {
        newGame()
        true
    }
    R.id.help -> {
        showHelp()
        true
    }
    else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
}
```

Comment: This opens the menu. Even if I only have on item in the menu, I need to click on it in order to change the activity